# Invalid element type when using Context to pass down Auth details

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently attempting to build an 'AuthContext' so I can use it in various screens and pass the data down.

I thought I'd built it right.. But when I try to call one of the functions in my Provider, it's throwing a component exception, stating 'element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined'.

Here is the context file:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';

import { Magic } from '@magic-sdk/react-native';
const m = new Magic('api key');

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const userSignedIn = async () => {
    // Call Magic logged in
    const loggedIn = await m.user.isLoggedIn();
    // If user logged in, save details to user, and redirect to dashboard
    if (loggedIn === true) {
      const { issuer, email } = await m.user.getMetaData();
      setUser([issuer, email])
      navigate('authorisedFlow')
      // If user not logged in, redirect to login flow
    } else {
      navigate('loginFlow')
    }
  };

  const signIn = () => {

  };

  const signUp = () => {

  };

  const logOut = () => {

  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, userSignedIn, signIn, signUp, logOut }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And here is the component which is attempting to use the context:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext';

const LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const { userSignedIn } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    userSignedIn()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

And finally, here is my app.js file (cut most of it out due to length, but wanted to show Provider):

```
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator)

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  )
};
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exported your `AuthContext` as a named-export ... but you're importing a default-export

```
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'; // <--- Here
const LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {};
```

Instead...

```
import { AuthContext}  from '../context/AuthContext';
```

Same goes for this one as well...

```
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';
```

Which should be

```
import { AuthContext: { Provider as AuthProvider } } from './src/context/AuthContext';
```

OR

```
import { AuthContext } from './src/context/AuthContext';

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider>
      <App />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you - that's working as expected. The useEffect function isn't firing but feel that's a different question. Have a great day!